# Simultaneous BLE GATT Client & Server issue on when client initiates disconnect

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I am working on the app for a dedicated device running Android.

The app starts GATT Server with a custom service and characteristics in order to provide communication between current device and connected to a GATT server device.

On the other hand, there is a separate logic, which initiates GATT client connection with the connected device in order to connect to the iOS ANCS server (if possible).
When GATT client fails to connect for any reason (no ANCS service, timeout, etc),it triggers disconnect using these two methods:

```
bluetoothGatt?.disconnect()
bluetoothGatt?.close()
```

The issue is that upon calling these methods, the GATT Server connection also disconnects - app receives a callback from a `BluetoothGattServerCallback.onConnectionStateChange` listener about the "Not Connected" state.

The Gatt Client and GATT Server logic are in a separate classes, they don't share any logic, they have a separate callbacks.

How it can be possible?
Does anyone had similar issues or I am missing something?